# How do I write a regex that allows for up to 7 characters plus one whitespace?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regex that allows for up to 7 characters plus **one** whitespace

Sorry I'm a complete novice at regex stuff

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

MODIFIED: The character can be either a letter or number...as it's for a postcode widget

Comment: \w{0,7}\s     -- that's off the top of my head, hopefully right! Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: It would be easier if you would be more specific. e.g. you could provide examples of what you want to match, and what not. I modified my answer, and I assume if you want to match UK postcodes the whitespace can not be anywhere in the string, but I don't know the exact definition of UK postcodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think

`/^\w{1,7}\s?$/`

which is

```
^       start of string  
\w      letters, numbers and underscore  
{1,7}   one to seven  
\s      whitespace  
?       zero or 1 of the preceding  - remove it if you want JUST one space  
$       end of string
```

If you do not want the underscore change `\w` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
If you want ANY character, change `\w` to a `.` (fullstop)

More here http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-intro.php

Answer (score 1):

This should match what you need:

```
\S{0,7}\s
```

Unfortunately you didn't specify what kind of characters you need to match.  So this one matches up to seven non-whitespace characters followed by a whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,7}\s$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7}\s
```

Comment: This matches only whitespaces as well.  I don't think that what OP has asked for.  Technically they are characters too, but in this case it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You are right, be he really didn't specify, what a "character" is for him.

Comment: & @detunized - The charcters can be either a letters or numbers

Answer (score 0):

`/[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,7}\s/`

7 chars followed by one whitespace character.

Comment: the whitespace can appear anywhere in the string

Comment: that would also match 7 whitespaces, he only wants one.

Answer (score 0):

- Exactly one whitespace: `/^.{0,7}\s$/`
- At least one whitespace: `/^.{0,7}\s+$/`
- Zero or one whitespace: `/^.{0,7}\s?$/`
- Zero or more whitspace: `/^.{0,7}\s*$/`

If you want to require at least one character before the whitespace, use `{1,7}`.